# Consulta de 4 tablas, sumando un campo agrupado por id (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una base de datos en MySQL con la siguiente estructura

**Tabla solicitud:**

id_solicitud | id_sucursal |  status_sucursal |

---

**Tabla enfriador:**

id_enfriador | id_solicitud | total_enfriador|

---

**Tabla maquina:**

id_maquina | id_solicitud | total_maquina|

---

**Tabla chatarra**

id_chatarra | id_solicitud | total_chatarra|

---

**La query debe quedar estructurada de la siguiente forma:**

id_solicitud|id_sucursal|SUM_TOT_ENFRI|SUM_TOT_MAQ|SUM_TOT_CHAT|status_sucursal

**Agrupando por id_solicitud, donde el id_sucursal sea 3 y el status_sucursal sea "Abierta" y donde muestre 0 los totales si mi suma sea igual a 0**

Tengo una consulta pero no funciona correctamente ya que me muestra 0 columnas como resultado:

**Query:**

```
SELECT sol.id_solicitud, sol.id_sucursal, SUM(enf.total_enfriador) as 
       SUM_TOT_ENFRI, SUM(maq.total_maquina) as SUM_TOT_MAQ, 
       SUM(cha.total_chatarra) as SUM_TOT_CHA, sol.status_sucursal 
FROM solicitud sol, enfriador enf, maquina maq, chatarra cha 
WHERE sol.id_solicitud = enf.id_solicitud 
      AND sol.id_solicitud = maq.id_solicitud  
      AND sol.id_solicitud = cha.id_solicitud 
      AND sol.id_sucursal = 3 
      AND sol.status_sucursal = 'Abierta'
GROUP BY sol.id_solicitud;
```

Comment: ¿Por que tienes esta parte, de esta forma? `FROM solicitud sol, enfriador enf, maquina maq, chatarra cha`

Comment: las tablas que voy a consultar con sus alias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema es que como esta estructurada tu consulta, con un join implicito, esta devolviendo solo registros donde encuentre coincidencias en todas las tablas.

Como podemos suponer tus datos, no creo que cada solicitud tenga siempre todos los items.

Entonces, lo que tendrias que hacer es un left join de solicitud a cada tabla, para asegurarte de siempre traer la solicitud, aunque no existan datos relacionados en las otras tablas.

```
SELECT sol.id_solicitud, sol.id_sucursal, SUM(enf.total_enfriador) as 
       SUM_TOT_ENFRI, SUM(maq.total_maquina) as SUM_TOT_MAQ, 
       SUM(cha.total_chatarra) as SUM_TOT_CHA, sol.status_sucursal 
FROM solicitud sol
LEFT JOIN enfriador enf ON sol.id_solicitud = enf.id_solicitud 
LEFT JOIN maquina maq ON sol.id_solicitud = maq.id_solicitud  
LEFT JOIN chatarra cha ON sol.id_solicitud = cha.id_solicitud 
WHERE sol.id_sucursal = 3 
      AND sol.status_sucursal = 'Abierta'
GROUP BY sol.id_solicitud, sol.id_sucursal;
```

Ademas agregue en tu group by el unico campo que no pertenece a ninguna función de agregación. Esto es porque mysql te permite hacer eso, pero no es correcto.

Si esto no termina de solucionar tu problema, fijate de ir agregando las tablas a tu query de a una, para verificar que no hay ningun error en algun lado

Answer (score 2):

```
GROUP BY sol.id_solicitud;
```

Te genera inconsistencias por la manera en que unes las tablas

```
solicitud sol, enfriador enf, maquina maq, chatarra cha
```

Lo que puedes hacer es poner tu query como un subquery dejando fuera el `GROUP BY` y quitando los alias

```
SELECT id_solicitud, id_sucursal, SUM(total_enfriador) as 
       SUM_TOT_ENFRI, SUM(total_maquina) as SUM_TOT_MAQ, 
       SUM(total_chatarra) as SUM_TOT_CHA, status_sucursal 
       (
        SELECT sol.id_solicitud, sol.id_sucursal, enf.total_enfriador, 
               maq.total_maquina, cha.total_chatarra, sol.status_sucursal 
        FROM solicitud sol, enfriador enf, maquina maq, chatarra cha 
        WHERE sol.id_solicitud = enf.id_solicitud 
              AND sol.id_solicitud = maq.id_solicitud  
              AND sol.id_solicitud = cha.id_solicitud 
              AND sol.id_sucursal = 3 
              AND sol.status_sucursal = 'Abierta'
      )
GROUP BY id_solicitud;
```

Comment: Me da el siguiente error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT sol.id_solicitud, sol.id_sucursal, enf.total_enfriador, 
               m' at line 5`

Comment: Revisa que los alias y nombres de campos sean iguales a los de tus tablas